# How to merge two cells in CSV file

Tags: excel, csv

How to merge two cell in CSV file like as Excel?

I want to merge two cell in CSV file file as:

```
Header         Id        Name                       mobileNo
Sub-Header     id   first Name last Name     countryCode  MobNumber
```

Comment: I don't understand why this question was down-voted. If you're going to down-vote at least put down a comment. Yes, it is a simple question but I don't see anything fundamentally wrong with it.

Comment: Check https://superuser.com/questions/940464/csv-input-for-merged-columns-in-microsoft-excel

Comment: I think this is a very interesting question and I support @Surya_Tej's answer, which says that it is impossible. CSV files represent tabular data, but not tables or table cells. Tabular data can also be referred to as a list of structs who share the same field names. The format is well explained in the [CSV format Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

Answer (score 13):

This is not possible

- A comma-separated values (CSV) file stores tabular data (numbers and
  text) in plain text.
- It is just data, with no attached formatting or knowledge of how the 
  cells should be merged when the data is imported.

You could use a script maybe like python to merge them, refer this link
https://dzone.com/articles/merging-cells

Answer (score -1):

You can just keep on adding comma's after a text in  one cell to merge it with other cells. It did work for me at least.

Comment: Please show example of what you mean.   This doesn't sound like what the OP was looking for.   I'm looking for a way to actually merge the cells, not just skip a few cells.

Comment: Show how it is done. Correctly type out a code implementation, please?