# Is there a better way of displaying a csv file that was made from a Multi-index dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format, multi-index

I was working on a project for calculating the different speeds of different algorithms with different datas and I wanted to save this data in a csv format and eventually view it in Excel.

I did this in the following lines of code:

```
df=DataFrame(dictionary_container,index=indexer)
df=df.transpose()
df.to_csv("sorted_results.csv")
print(df)
```

Now, the problem is that my data frame has a multi-index and it seems like when this multi-index is converted into csv it doesn't has the same format and adaptation DataFrame has.

When printed as a dataframe in my pycharm console it looks something like this:

```
                         Selection Sort                           Bubble Sort                         Insertion Sort                            Shell Sort                            Merge Sort                            Quick Sort                      
                       Data Comparisons Data Swaps      Time Data Comparisons Data Swaps       Time Data Comparisons Data Swaps      Time Data Comparisons Data Swaps      Time Data Comparisons Data Swaps      Time Data Comparisons  Data Swaps      Time
Ascending_Sorted_250            31125.0        0.0  0.008000          61752.0        0.0   0.008000            249.0        0.0  0.000000           1506.0        0.0  0.000000         102985.0        0.0  0.000000          32220.0     16110.0  0.007996
Ascending_Sorted_500           124750.0        0.0  0.008002         248502.0        0.0   0.038870            499.0        0.0  0.002037           3506.0        0.0  0.000000         466830.0        0.0  0.008044         130682.0     65341.0  0.012074
Ascending_Sorted_1000          499500.0        0.0  0.048405         997002.0        0.0   0.124397            999.0        0.0  0.000000           8006.0        0.0  0.009063        2091964.0        0.0  0.031324         542432.0    271216.0  0.029222
Descending_Sorted_250           31125.0      144.0  0.002518          61752.0        0.0   0.007534            249.0    31005.0  0.000000           1506.0      867.0  0.008008          98029.0        0.0  0.000000          62250.0     31125.0  0.008001
Descending_Sorted_500          124750.0      304.0  0.016446         248502.0        0.0   0.058094            499.0   124499.0  0.021138           3506.0     1988.0  0.007011         450069.0        0.0  0.017184         249500.0    124750.0  0.008066
Descending_Sorted_1000         499500.0      627.0  0.057602         997002.0        0.0   0.211443            999.0   498961.0  0.121921           8006.0     4480.0  0.009598        2038910.0        0.0  0.036352         999000.0    499500.0  0.051927
Unordered_Sorted_250            31125.0      247.0  0.000000          61752.0        0.0   0.008011            249.0    16176.0  0.008005           1506.0     1190.0  0.000000         119646.0        0.0  0.008008         102818.0     51409.0  0.000000
Unordered_Sorted_500           124750.0      497.0  0.016108         248502.0        0.0   0.032092            499.0    62517.0  0.014741           3506.0     3038.0  0.002054         546612.0        0.0  0.010065         433998.0    216999.0  0.000000
Unordered_Sorted_1000          499500.0      991.0  0.050410         997002.0        0.0   0.148675            999.0   238976.0  0.062542           8006.0     6602.0  0.000000        2631656.0        0.0  0.032139        2001812.0   1000906.0  0.008013
Ascending_Sorted_2000        49995000.0        0.0  5.434769       99970002.0        0.0  13.766283           9999.0        0.0  0.022327         120005.0        0.0  0.057448      314528524.0        0.0  0.392050       65294480.0  32647240.0  0.897377
Descending_Sorted_2000        1999000.0     1249.0  0.216450        3994002.0        0.0   0.796005           1999.0  1997998.0  0.476391          18006.0     9947.0  0.016075        9127864.0        0.0  0.054320        3998000.0   1999000.0  0.181211
Unordered_Sorted_2000         1999000.0     1997.0  0.270270        3994002.0        0.0   0.633384           1999.0   975989.0  0.272254          18006.0    17558.0  0.007661       11645237.0        0.0  0.072448        8575300.0   4287650.0  0.007999
```

But when displayed in csv(sorted_results.csv) it looks like this which is very off putting:
[image]

But I want it to look something like this which is very formal and way better:
[image]

The first level of the multi index is repeated and I do not want that

I tried everything I tried replacing the second and third repetitions with `pd.NA` or `numpy.NaN` or even `None` but even then it will actually display ,nan or None in the indexes, respectively, and I don't want that I want it to be empty over there.

I did search for solutions on stack overflow, and I did end up stumbling upon something but the solutions/python scripts had to deal with using os to actually affect the already created csv file.

I also tried to use style.format but apparently this only helps with CSS styles and usually helps with color and stuff. Also I don't know how much it would help with a .csv file.

Comment: Indeed, you want a cell column fusion instruction sent from Pandas ? If so, this question already has an answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50488905/how-to-merge-two-cells-in-csv-file

Comment: The answer is not very specific to what I am trying to do. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve this functionality with a `csv` since it is a simple file format. You'd have to create an `excel` file utilizing the `to_excel()` in pandas. Then use an excel manipulating library like `openpyxl`.

```
df=DataFrame(dictionary_container,index=indexer)
df=df.transpose()
df.to_excel("sorted_results.xlsx")
```

Then we can use openpyxl get the desired results:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font
from openpyxl.styles.alignment import Alignment

# Read the excel file and get worksheet
wb = load_workbook(filename="sorted_results.xlsx", data_only=True)
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
max_cols = ws.max_column

# Cell Formatting
font = Font(name='Arial', b=True)
center = Alignment(horizontal="center")

# Insert the sorting results header
ws.insert_rows(1)
ws.merge_cells(start_row=1, start_column=2, end_row=1, end_column=max_cols)
header = ws.cell(row=1, column=2)
header.value = "Sorting Results"
header.font = font
header.alignment = center

# Make all values in column a bold
for cell in ws['A']:
    cell.font = font

for col in range(2, ws.max_column+1):
    # Merge the second header cells
    if (col - 2) % 3 == 0 :
        ws.merge_cells(start_row=2, start_column=col, end_row=2, end_column=col+2)
        cell = ws.cell(row=2, column=col)
        cell.font = font
        cell.alignment = center
    # Bold cells in 3rd row
    cell = ws.cell(row=3, column=col)
    cell.font = font

wb.save('sorted_results.xlsx')
```

This gives me the following results:
[image: output]

With this input excel sheet:
[image: input]

**Note**: `data` is just a placeholder I added for examples sake.

Comment: This is great! This was the thing that I was absolutely looking for. I am kind of new to using pandas.

Comment: @Howwhy may I ask why this answer was unaccepted?

Comment: I realized after implementing it that it would directly save it as a .xlsx file and even after that when converting it into .csv using python it would lose all its structure and wouldn't be in the right format, so if you have an implementation that could do what you did above but for a csv then that would be verified.

Comment: @Howwhy I see. Unfortunately, when it comes to `csv`, you can't do any sort of `formatting` or `cell merging` since it's a simple file format. As the [name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) suggest, it is a text file that use a comma to separate values and each line is a row. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50489242/11286032) is an answer that speaks more on the matter.